# jQuery, Prevent Sortable and Draggable AFTER Dropping into cell

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Objective: I DO want to drag and drop.  I DO want to sort between cells.  However, once a cell is filled, I do not want to be able to drop/sort another item into the cell.  It should be off limits.  I've been able to successfully disable the drag/drop by using the following:

```
$(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
```

I have everything working except that I can still drag/sort into the cell from another cell.  I noticed that the Stop event is being called when I do this.  It would be nice if I could disable the 'stop' like I disabled the 'drop' in the above line of code.

Here is a fiddle that shows my issue:
[Fiddle Me This](http://jsfiddle.net/uTydW/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up having to do (see the 'receive' event).  It seems that there might be a cleaner way, but this works:

```
    $(".droppedFields").sortable({
        cancel: null, // Cancel the default events on the controls
        connectWith: ".droppedFields",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            makeUnDroppable();
        },
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            var source = ui.item;
            var target = $(this);

            var newCombinedTargetLength = target.text().length;
            var sourceLength = source.text().length;

            // cancel the sort if something is already there
            if (newCombinedTargetLength - sourceLength > 0) {
                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }            
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```